What advantages would horns present in humans?
In my canon, an advanced civilization exists that has a pre-established penchant for extensive bodily modification. While their extra thumb and tail are indeed useful for additional dexterity and balance respectively, they are mostly quirks they have out of my desire to build their physiology that way.
In keeping with bodily modifications that have actually useful advantages, what advantages would horns present in a humanoid body plan? Assume horns of any type within the constraints of what is found in organisms in our own biosphere, and a human body that's wholly the same as ours beyond the extra thumb and tail as mentioned above.

Unless you define the specific environment there is no way to tell what advantages something might bring. Per [help]: narrow scope. You are not defining the horn type nor the environment, we can't do a full comparative study on all the possible combinations.

Yeah the environment is pretty critical. If your universe has people battling in coliseums with no weapons other than their bodies, then sure a pointy horn is good. If your universe people work in offices then a pointy horn is probably going to keep making a mess and cause workplace injuries.

What advantages do you want those horns to give?

Related posts: Most effective shaped horn (horns)/ crest for a head butting human? • How would I evolve horns on humans? • Without making any changes to the human neck, how large of horns could a human being support? • How horny can humans get before it's too horny

VTC:Needs More Detail. Without knowing the specific nature of the horns, this is impractical brainstorming. Animals have small horns and large horns on similar-sized heads. They have curved horns and straight horns. They have single-prong and multi-prong horns and thick horns and thin horns.... Some uses of the horns are common while others are not. Now that I think about it, -1 for apparently not researching how animals use their horns.

@JBH His question is about choosing what style of horn would be most practical in a technologically advanced setting. Since he needs form to follow function, it would be counterproductive to further define what the horns should look like since what they will look like needs to be based on whatever the best function we can come up with might be.

@Nosajimiki Either tell us how the horns are designed and we'll explain how they can be used, or tell us how they are to be used and we'll tell you the designs that will work. Asking for both is VTC:Needs More Focus at best. Ignoring the design and asking for us to brainstorm possible solutions is VTC:Not About WB Per the [help] (open-ended, all answers of equal value). Hopefully you're working with me over in Meta to redesign the help center because I believe the current rule balance for the site is off. But for now, them be the rules.

@JBH Nevermind, re-reading the question, this definitely falls under brainstorming category.

Mostly aesthetic
Animal species that have horns use them mostly for combat, defending themselves against predators, fighting off mating rivals and defending their territory. For a quadruped animal horns are very useful, many of these species use all limbs for moving, so their only other weapons would be their teeth (or just charging the enemy). You'll notice that animals that have claws do not usually have horns.
For humanoids, horns are a liability in combat. Human combat mainly evolved around designing ways to poke their enemies with pointy sticks while being too far to be poked themselves. That's how you got spears, javelins, arrows and eventually bullets. The only way to use horns in combat would involve charging and basically headbutting the enemy. That would bring you in close range and that alone would make you vulnerable. In addition, the head-first charge would make it difficult to balance and expose your head and neck. On top of that, horns make it difficult to use helmets, which protect the all-important brain. Even a successful attack with horns risks damage to the brain from the impact.
Some species also use horns as tools for digging up plant roots for example, but for humanoids it would be far easier and more effective to make tools for that purpose.
So the only remaining use for horns is aesthetic. For males, horns would be a very visible secondary sexual characteristic, powerful looking horns would be seen as a sign of strength and virility. Females of your species would paint horns in a range of colors, hang jewellery on them and perhaps chisel them into aesthetically pleasing shapes.

Technology carriers
Biologically horns aren't useful to humans. Especially in a world advanced enough for such bioengineering there seems to be no use case. I assume that sexual interest is not considered 'useful', though someone could show their affluence with special horns. They aren't for defence or attack, as our body plan is uniquely unsuitable for this purpose, and again, the technology is so advanced it shouldn't be needed. You could argue that it expands space for brains or immune systems. For brains you could make a use case of brain cells that do not have a blood brain barrier. It makes that part very vulnerable, but also incredibly flexible and quick to grow. This way you could add some highly specialised brain area's that can be easily rebuild after disease or a particularly hard bump against the horns, making it flexible and fast learning. Then again, you can have much better options than horns.
That leaves technology. This can be anything from communication that is then plugged into the brain, like a cohear implant, or a HUD/HDD in the eyes, to things facilitating the human. Think of drugs and hormones to regulate perfect sleep or go on a bit longer, control stress, immune system or whatever. You can even go further with sci-fi with storage or the like. You might argue that, just like the extra brains, better methods can be applied. That being said, horns provide a separation of some more dangerous chemicals from the body, like chemicals in batteries, as well as less chance it is rejected by the body, as it is technically outside the body, in a cavity of the horns. It might have started with small extrusions on the head, becoming more elaborate over time into horns as the functions and thus size of the technology grew.
Conclusion
Unless you add some further reasoning horns would never be chosen for practicality. Only aesthetically they make sense. Find an extra in universe reason that make the horns practical, like technology or some organ inside that needs to be exactly there.

Antennas
So, your civilization wants to expand the EM or sound wavelengths it can work with - pretty simple to do for many of them, but the downside is that, if you really want to work with radiowaves, or infrasound, you need some specialist structures. Horns are perfect - a nice structure to include the hardware for this inside, and located near enough to the optic nerve that it's not a crazy connection for the structure to simply hook in there. And, bingo, you can see in radio!
Of course, practical use: limited. Cool factor: high. I'd argue these might, in a dystopian society, become one of the social signifiers or means of communication between the very wealthy ("Oh, darling, you simply can't tell how stunning those clothes look in radio, so clever of them to weave  microRF tags all through them. Of course, you couldn't possibly appreciate it, as an unhorned member of society")
You even might see different social or subcultures develop, from art displays perceivable only by the wealthy horn wearers, to subcultures that set up radiotransmitters all through their clubs, to stop any of those "bleeding spiky bastards" coming in without physical pain. You could even imagine different grades of horns, that let their wearers see further into the spectrum.

The same as the reason horns exist in other animals, sexual display. Males grow horns to make themselves look visibly male (the same reason peacocks have their tails, or why human males sometimes grow beards).

Not so different from male humans growing beards.

I was going to comment about Vikings wearing horned helmets, but apparently that is false, although the Smithsonian article does not indicate why horns are significant, other than "because symbolism".

@GregBurghardt Vikings (As in the cultures of Northern Europe during the Early Medieval period) did not, but there is some evidence that both horned and winged helmets may have been somewhat common during the Hallstatt Period 1200BC-450BC.  There is also the Japanese Kabuto which often featured horn-like embellishments which looked ornemental, but were specifically designed to deflect attacks that would otherwise be able to hit on the flat of the helmet.

Reuseable blades
The advanced civilization often goes to explore interesting places and colonize new lands. Those places often don't have smiths or factories to forge needed equipment. Horns are an easy, out of the way method to grow blades which are completely organic and not dependent on supply chains.
The horns grow quickly, can be snapped off easily, are easily customizable with commonly known grooming rituals, and are out of the way of any task that requires hands. More bespoke examples can even produce diamond blades to help industrial equipment.

Built in Bike Helmet
Motorcycles, cars, speed boats... humans love to go way faster than we are naturally designed to go, and we do it so often that high speed crashes have become one of the leading causes of death in humans... but unlike us, certain horned animals like rams are able to take some pretty high speed head on hits thanks to thier horns which basically work like a built in motorcycle helmet. If you take the general concept of ram horns, but reshape them to start low and on our forehead, and then wrap over the top and around the sides of the skull, they will form a sort of helmet providing protection against impacts to the front, top, and sides of our heads giving our brains a significant survival advantage in case of an auto-accident.
And because they are horns, and not bones, they can be designed act as crumple zone, so that in case of a catastrophic hit, the horns can crack, crush, and snap off while saving our skulls and brains underneath, then regrown just like a chipped fingernail.


Protection from head injury?
I imagine in like a Mad Max type of environment, where people spend a lot of time getting thrown out of moving vehicles, ram-like horns which wrap around the top and sides of the head would be pretty useful in preventing brain damage. In a hard crash, the horns would take the impact and crush or break, leaving the skull intact. Handy in a fist fight, too.
For max protection, maybe some ram horns on the sides plus a row of short spikes down the middle.
They wouldn't provide any advantage that a helmet doesn't, and they'd make it difficult to wear a helmet. But if these people prefer body mods to gadgets and suffer a lot of blunt force trauma, horns some make sense.
